# Multi row-col figures in latex with independent captions

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to attach my figure like the below paper.

Like the below figure, I'll align figures in 2*3 matrix

with the independent figure or grouped subfigure.

How I can make it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take look at the `floatrow` and `subcaption` packages.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is aligning on top *and* aligning the captions. Solved with a tabular.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.025\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}
\caption{Instantaneous impact}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}
\caption{Near effect}
\end{subfigure} \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}p{0.3\textwidth}}{\caption{Handover Duration}} &
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.65\textwidth}@{}}{\caption{Handover-centric Analysis of CUBIC}} \\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}
\caption{Instantaneous impact}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}
\caption{Near effect}
\end{subfigure} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{0.65\textwidth}@{}}{\caption{Handover-centric Analysis of BBR}} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{0.3\textwidth}@{}}{\caption{Comparative Performance}} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The magic `0.025\textwidth` is because we need four `\tabcolsep` spaces around the central column; the images' widths are `0.3\textwidth`. For the `0.65\textwidth`, we add to the column width two `\tabcolsep` spaces.

[image]

Comment: Wow! you are a genius! Thank you